# merge arrays without reindexing keys

Tags: php

I have two arrays that I want to merge recursively, so adding arrays is not an option. This is simple example without multilevels to demonstrate the problem:

```
$a1 = Array(
    5 => 'pronoun'
)
$a2 = Array(
    2 => 'verb',
    3 => 'noun'
)

$r = array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2)
```

And I want to get that resulting array:

```
Array(
    5 => 'pronoun'
    2 => 'verb',
    3 => 'noun'
)
```

My problem is that `array_merge_recursive` function reindixes keys, and I get the following:

```
Array(
    0 => 'pronoun'
    1 => 'verb',
    2 => 'noun'
)
```

I understand that's happening because all my keys are numeric. So I tried to make them string when adding but it doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
$a1[(string)7] = 'some value';
```

The key - 7 - is still number, or at least that's how it is displayed in debugger - `$a1[7]` and not `$a1['7']`. Any advice?

EDIT:
Addition of arrays is not an option. Please see why. I have two multilevel arrays:

```
$a1 = array (
            1 => array (
                1 => "man1",
                2 => "man"
            ),
            2 => array (
                1 => "run",
                2 => "nice"
            )
        );

        $a2 = array(
            2 => array (
                1 => "to observe",
                2 => "to examine visually"),
            3 => array(
                1 => "look nice",
                2 => "appear, seem to be"));

        $r = $a1 + $a2;
```

What I expect is the following:

```
$r = Array(
...
2 => array(
    1 => array("run", "to observe")
    2 => array("nice", "to examine visually")
));
```

But instead the options for the key 2 from the second array is not added:

```
$r = Array(
...
2 => array(
    1 => "run",
    2 => "nice"
));
```

Comment: As for string keys, if it looks numeric and is smaller than PHP_INT_MAX, it will always be casted to int. Remember to check [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#106985) under manual pages, usually you can find answer for such common problems there.

Comment: You are expecting impossible result. Array can not have two identical keys.

Comment: you cannot have what you expect in any language known to me (cannot have duplicate key)

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, I made edits to my question. Please see what I need once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should apply to your particular problem:

```
function assoc_merge(array $a, array $b)
{
    $r = array();

    foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $b) && is_array($val) == is_array($b[$key])) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $r[$key] = assoc_merge($a[$key], $b[$key]); // merge array
            } else {
                $r[$key] = array($val, $b[$key]); // merge entry
            }
        } else {
            $r[$key] = $val; // just copy
        }
    }
    return $r + $b; // add whatever we missed
}

print_r(assoc_merge($a1, $a2));
```

Comment: @Maximus Why don't you try and let me know? ;-)

Comment: I checked :). It doesn't do what I want. Becase replaces duplicate values, and I want to merge them. See the key '2' from my array and the result I want to get.

Comment: @Maximus You're right, I read past that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Super! It works perfectly now. Thanks! The only thing is that you used $value instead of $val variable in two instances, I edited that and it did the trick. Maybe you'd want to edit your response. Best, M

Answer (score 3):

you can just use `$a1+$a2` to get your result

```
$a1 = array(
    5 => 'pronoun'
);
$a2 = array(
    2 => 'verb',
    3 => 'noun'
);
print_r($a1+$a2);
```

For recursive array

```
$a1 = array(
    5 => 'pronoun'
);
$a2 = array(array('a', 'z'), array(2 => 'p', 'q'));
print_r($a1+$a2);
```

Result is

```
Array
(
    [5] => pronoun
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => p
            [3] => q
        )

)
```

is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Does this handle recursive merges? I'm not sure how this would work if `$a2` was `$a2 = array(array('a', 'z'), array(2 => 'p', 'q'));`. Maybe try it? Dunno what it returns in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the manual case.

```
function merge () { // takes any number of arguments
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  $result = array();
  foreach ($arrays as $array)
    foreach ($array as $key => $item)
      if (is_array($item))
        $result = merge($result, $item);
      else
        $result[$key] = $item;
  return $result;
```

Sure, it's slow, but it will work.

Comment: Shouldn't `$result = merge($result, $item);` be `$result[$key] = merge($result[$key], $item);`?

Comment: As I see it, a recursive merge would merge all elements in the top-level, therefore merging the elements in the sub-array with the result. Either way, keep in mind that `$result[$key]` should be unset under your implementation by the time that line is reached, making it throw an exception and become an obscure way of doing, once again, `$result[$key] = $item;` (bar the exception). If recursivity isn't desired, the `if` is unnecessary and only the `else` branch should remain (as the only one); if it is, then the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = array(
    5 => 'pronoun'
);
$a2 = array(
    2 => 'verb',
    3 => 'noun'
);
foreach($a2 as $key=>$value) {
    $a1[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($a1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = [ 5 => 'pronoun'];
$b = [ 2 => 'verb', 3 => 'noun'];

$m = array_merge(array_keys($a), array_keys($b));
$final = array_combine($m, array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
```

`print_r($final);`